# Losing scope on recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, scoping

I'm creating a module that accepts a data set and an integer n and recursively fills that dataset with n products at a time, after the first call, the function loses its scope and errors out. Why, And what's the best practice for fixing this?

Code:

```
function ProductFactory(){

    var bigArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var smallArr = [1,2,3,4];

    return {
        getProductList: getProductList,
        getAllProducts: getAllProducts
    };

    function getProductList(start, size){ return start < 5 ? bigArr : smallArr }

    function getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet) {
        var startPage = dataSet.length / batchSizeRequested;
        var productBatch = this.getProductList(startPage, batchSizeRequested);
        dataSet = dataSet.concat(productBatch);
        if (productBatch.length === batchSizeRequested)
            getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet);
    }
}

var productGetter = new ProductFactory();

productGetter.getAllProducts(10, []);
```

Comment: you need to make your recursive call involve `this.` just like you did with the call to `getProductList()`.

Answer (score 2):

1) First of all you shouldn't call `getProductList` using `this`, in this case you can just call it as it is, because `getProductList` is not a function that was assigned directly to this object. It is just a closure that uses local variables in it's code. If you want to call function using `this`, you should assign it using `this`, for example  `this.getProductList = function() {}` 
2) I don't think there are other scoping problems except redundant `this`, but I found another issue, though.
You are not actually return anything from your function, plus recursive call does not have an exit point.
Fixed code looks like this.

```
function ProductFactory(){

    var bigArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var smallArr = [1,2,3,4];

    return {
        getProductList: getProductList,
        getAllProducts: getAllProducts
    };

    function getProductList(start, size){ return start < 5 ? bigArr : smallArr }

    function getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet) {
        var startPage = dataSet.length / batchSizeRequested;
        var productBatch = getProductList(startPage, batchSizeRequested);
        dataSet = dataSet.concat(productBatch);
        if (productBatch.length === batchSizeRequested) {
            return getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet);
        } else {
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
}

var productGetter = ProductFactory();
var products = productGetter.getAllProducts(10, []);

console.log(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach to a function call like this is to assign an external value to `this` (typically called `self`):

```
function ProductFactory(){
  ...
  var self = this;
  function getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet) {
    ...
    getAllProducts.apply(self, [batchSizeRequested, dataSet]);
  }
}
```

In this case, however, please try to remember that you have defined a closure function `getAllProducts` that is only privately accessible internal to the constructor. Instead you should probably do:

```
function ProductFactory(){
  ...
  var self = this;
  this.getAllProducts = function(batchSizeRequested, dataSet) {
    ...
    self.getAllProducts(batchSizeRequested, dataSet);
  }
}
```